# Attempted update of read-only column error on AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to create a trigger on firebird 2.5 to update a column when another column is updated. I have created a example simple table for my attempts.

```
create tablea (estado char(1), fl_previa_laudo char(1));
```

And my trigger is like this:

```
create trigger ATUALIZA_PREVIA_AI for TABLEA
active after update position 0
as
begin

if( old.estado in ('3', '4', '7', '8') ) then
    new.fl_previa_laudo = 'T';
else 
    new.fl_previa_laudo = 'F';
end;
```

And when I run the trigger it gives an error:

> can't format message 13:849 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg
>   not found. attempted update of read-only column.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a column in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, but that is not possible. If you want to modify a value, then you need to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. See to [Firebird documentation on triggers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-triggers), specifically (emphasis mine):

> The `NEW` and `OLD` variables are subject to some rules:
>
> - In all triggers, the `OLD` value is read-only
> - In `BEFORE UPDATE` and `BEFORE INSERT` code, the `NEW` value is read/write, unless it is a `COMPUTED BY` column
> - In `INSERT` triggers, references to the `OLD` variables are invalid and will throw an exception
> - In `DELETE` triggers, references to the `NEW` variables are invalid and will throw an exception
> - **In all `AFTER` trigger code, the `NEW` variables are read-only**

In other words, a `before update` trigger allows you to modify values before the row is persisted, while an `after update` trigger fires after the row has been persisted, allowing you to see the definitive values.